# How can I work around SQL Server - Inline Table Value Function execution plan variation based on parameters?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-execution-plan, user-defined-functions

Here is the situation:
I have a table value function with a datetime parameter ,lest's say tdf(p_date) ,
that filters about two million rows selecting those with column date smaller than p_date and computes some aggregate values on other columns.
It works great but if p_date is a custom scalar value function (returning the end of day in my case) the execution plan is altered an the query goes from 1 sec to 1 minute execution time.

A proof of concept table - 1K products, 2M rows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[POC](
    [Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [idProduct] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Quantity] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

The inline table value function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION tdf (@p_date datetime)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT idProduct, SUM(Quantity) AS TotalQuantity,
         max(Date) as LastDate
    FROM POC
    WHERE (Date < @p_date)
    GROUP BY idProduct
)
```

The scalar value function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[EndOfDay] (@date datetime)
RETURNS datetime
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @res datetime
    SET @res=dateadd(second, -1,
         dateadd(day, 1, 
             dateadd(ms, -datepart(ms, @date),
                 dateadd(ss, -datepart(ss, @date),
                    dateadd(mi,- datepart(mi,@date),
                         dateadd(hh, -datepart(hh, @date), @date))))))
    RETURN @res
END
```

Query 1 - Working great

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[tdf] (getdate())
```

The end of execution plan: 
Stream Aggregate Cost 13% <--- Clustered Index Scan Cost 86%

Query 2 - Not so great

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[tdf] (dbo.EndOfDay(getdate()))
```

The end of execution plan: 
Stream Aggregate Cost 4% <--- Filter Cost 12% <--- Clustered Index Scan Cost 86%

Comment: SQL code to illustrate exactly what you mean would be helpful.

Comment: I posted the code needed to replicate the execution plan variation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The overhead is your scalar function.

The TVF here is expanded like an inline macro so

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[tdf] (getdate())
```

becomes

```
SELECT     idProduct, SUM(Quantity) AS TotalQuantity, max(Date) as LastDate
    FROM         POC
    WHERE     Date < getdate()
    GROUP BY idProduct
```

When you use end of day scalar function, SQL can not evaluate the EOD(GETDATE()) as a constant.
I can't find my article quickly on how SQL evaluates this stuff, sorry.

I guess that it's being evaluated for each row, not upfront as you want.

I'd calulate the EOD statement separately:

```
DECLARE @eod datetime;
SET @eod = dbo.EndOfDay(getdate());
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[tdf] (@eod)
```

I'd also use this for the EOD function:

```
DATEADD(second, -1, DATEADD(day, 1, (DATEDIFF(day, 0, @date))))
```

[EDIT: Other question I answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311026/does-query-plan-optimizer-works-well-with-joined-filtered-table-valued-functions)

Comment: Agree scalar functions are almost alawys run row by row and thus should be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite EndOfDay as an inline UDF too, and use nested inline UDFs. Examples:

[Many nested inline UDFs are very fast](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2009/06/18/many-nested-inline-udfs-are-very-fast.aspx)

[Calculating third Wednesday of the month with inline UDFs](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2009/06/21/calculating-third-wednesday-of-the-month-with-inline-udfs.aspx)