# T-SQL Process Design and Execution Plan (UDF Parameter Sniffing?)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-execution-plan, parameter-sniffing

On SQL Server 2005, I have a complex multi-level allocation process which looks like this (pseudo-SQL):

```
FOR EACH @LVL_NUM < @MAX_LVL:
INSERT INTO ALLOCS
SELECT 'OUT', *
FROM BALANCES(@LVL_NUM)
INNER JOIN ALLOCN_SUMRY(@LVL_NUM)

INSERT INTO ALLOCS
SELECT 'IN', *
FROM BALANCES(@LVL_NUM)
INNER JOIN ALLOCNS(@LVL_NUM)
INNER JOIN ALLOCN_SUMRY(@LVL_NUM)
```

Where `ALLOCS` is seeded with direct allocations and then `BALANCES(@LVL_NUM)` is based on `ALLOCS` at the `@LVL_NUM` (which might be some direct allocations plus some IN allocations from a previous level) and `ALOCNS(@LVL_NUM)` is based on `BALANCES(@LVL_NUM)` and `ALOCN_SUMRY(@LVL_NUM)` is simply based on `ALOCNS(@LVL_NUM)` - with a lot of configuration tables which indicate the drivers which drive the allocations out.

This is simplified, but there are actually four or five pairs like this within the loop because there are a variety of logics which are not possible to handle together (and some cases which are possible to handle together.)

The basic logic is to take the total amount in a particular cost center/product line/etc (i.e. the `BALANCES`) and then allocate it out to another cost center/product line/etc based on its share (i.e. the `ALLOCNS / ALLOCN_SUMRY` percentage share) of a particular metric.

With so much logic repeated in the `OUT` recordkeeping and the `IN`, and of course the `SUMRY` based on the `ALLOCN` detail, I ended up implementing using inline table value functions, which seem to perform fairly well (and they match the existing system's behaviour in the regression tests, which is a plus!).  (The existing system is a monster C/C++/MFC/ODBC program that reads all the data into massive arrays and other data structures and is pretty atrociously written.)

The problem appears to be that when run in the loop I appear to be getting execution plan issues as I work my way up the levels as the `ALLOCS` table starts to change (and everything is changing, because the levels have different cost centers, so the configuration being used to drive the `ALLOCNS` is changing).  I have up to 99 levels, I think, but the lowest levels start 2, 4, 6.  It appears that running `@LVL_NUM = 6` by itself outside of the UDF performs fine, but that the UDF performs poorly - presumably because the UDF has a cached plan or that the overall plan is already bad because of the `ALLOCS` added from earlier steps at `@LVL_NUM IN (2, 4)`.

Earlier in development, I managed to get 30 levels run in 30 minutes, but now I can't get it to complete the first 3 levels in 2 hours.

I'm considering running the two inserts within another SP and calling it WITH RECOMPILE, but was curious if this RECOMPILE cascades properly into the TVF UDFs?  Any other advice would also be appreciated.

Real Code:

```
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [MISProcess].[udf_MR_BALANCES_STAT_UNI]    Script Date: 05/14/2009 22:16:09 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE FUNCTION [MISProcess].[udf_MR_BALANCES_STAT_UNI] (
     @DATA_DT_ID int
    ,@LVL_NUM int
    )
RETURNS TABLE
--    WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS 
RETURN
    (
     SELECT AB.YYMM_ID
           ,AB.BUS_UNIT_ID
           ,AB.BUS_UNIT_PROD_LINE_CD
--                   ,AB.ALOCN_SRC_CD
           ,AB.ALOCN_SRC_PROD_LINE_CD
           ,CASE WHEN ORIG_ALSRC.ALOCN_TYPE_CD = 'C'
                      AND ORIG_ALSRC.RETN_IND = 'Y' THEN AB.ORIG_ALOCN_SRC_CD
                 ELSE AB.BUS_UNIT_ID
            END AS ORIG_ALOCN_SRC_CD
           ,CASE WHEN BUPALSRC.COLLAPSE_IND = 'Y'
                 THEN BUPLNTM.ALOCN_LINE_ITEM_NUM
                 ELSE AB.LINE_ITEM_NUM
            END AS ALOCN_LINE_ITEM_NUM
           ,SUM(BUPLNTM.ALOCN_SIGN_IND * AB.ANULZD_ACTL_BAL) AS ANULZD_ACTL_BAL
     FROM   MISWork.vwMR_BALANCES AS AB
     INNER JOIN MISProcess.LKP_BUPLNTM AS BUPLNTM
            ON BUPLNTM.DATA_DT_ID = @DATA_DT_ID
               AND BUPLNTM.LINE_ITEM_NUM = AB.LINE_ITEM_NUM
               AND BUPLNTM.ALOCN_LINE_ITEM_NUM <> 0
     INNER JOIN [MISProcess].[udf_MR_ALSRC](@DATA_DT_ID, @LVL_NUM) AS BUPALSRC
            ON BUPALSRC.ALOCN_SRC_CD = AB.BUS_UNIT_ID
     INNER JOIN [MISProcess].LKP_BUPALSRC AS ORIG_ALSRC
            ON ORIG_ALSRC.DATA_DT_ID = @DATA_DT_ID
               AND ORIG_ALSRC.ALOCN_SRC_CD = AB.ORIG_ALOCN_SRC_CD
     GROUP BY AB.YYMM_ID
           ,AB.BUS_UNIT_ID
           ,AB.BUS_UNIT_PROD_LINE_CD
--                   ,AB.ALOCN_SRC_CD
           ,AB.ALOCN_SRC_PROD_LINE_CD
           ,CASE WHEN ORIG_ALSRC.ALOCN_TYPE_CD = 'C'
                      AND ORIG_ALSRC.RETN_IND = 'Y' THEN AB.ORIG_ALOCN_SRC_CD
                 ELSE AB.BUS_UNIT_ID
            END
           ,CASE WHEN BUPALSRC.COLLAPSE_IND = 'Y'
                 THEN BUPLNTM.ALOCN_LINE_ITEM_NUM
                 ELSE AB.LINE_ITEM_NUM
            END
    )

/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [MISProcess].[udf_MR_ALOCNS_STAT_UNI]    Script Date: 05/14/2009 22:16:16 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE FUNCTION [MISProcess].[udf_MR_ALOCNS_STAT_UNI] (
     @DATA_DT_ID int
    ,@LVL_NUM int
    )
RETURNS TABLE
--    WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS 
RETURN
    (
     SELECT BALANCES.YYMM_ID
           ,BS.ALOCN_SRC_CD AS BUS_UNIT_ID
           ,BS.PROD_LINE_CD AS BUS_UNIT_PROD_LINE_CD
           ,BALANCES.BUS_UNIT_ID AS ALOCN_SRC_CD
           ,BALANCES.BUS_UNIT_PROD_LINE_CD AS ALOCN_SRC_PROD_LINE_CD
           ,BALANCES.ORIG_ALOCN_SRC_CD
           ,BALANCES.ALOCN_LINE_ITEM_NUM
           ,SUM(BS.ACCT_STATS_CNT) AS ACCT_STATS_CNT
     FROM   [MISProcess].[udf_MR_BALANCES_STAT_UNI](@DATA_DT_ID, @LVL_NUM) AS BALANCES
     INNER JOIN [MISProcess].[udf_MR_ALSRC](@DATA_DT_ID, @LVL_NUM) AS BUPALSRC
            ON BUPALSRC.ALOCN_SRC_CD = BALANCES.BUS_UNIT_ID
     INNER JOIN MISProcess.LKP_PRODLINE AS PRODLINE
            ON PRODLINE.DATA_DT_ID = @DATA_DT_ID
               AND PRODLINE.PROD_LINE_CD = BALANCES.BUS_UNIT_PROD_LINE_CD
     INNER JOIN PUASFIN.FocusResults.BS AS BS
            ON BS.YYMM_ID = BALANCES.YYMM_ID
               AND BS.ALOCN_BASE_CD = BUPALSRC.ALOCN_BASE_CD
               AND BS.ALOCN_SRC_CD <> BALANCES.BUS_UNIT_ID
               AND (
                    PRODLINE.GENRC_PROD_LINE_IND = 'Y'
                    OR BS.PROD_LINE_CD = BALANCES.BUS_UNIT_PROD_LINE_CD
                   )
     INNER JOIN [MISProcess].[udf_MR_ALSRC](@DATA_DT_ID, 0) AS DEST_BUP_ALSRC
            ON DEST_BUP_ALSRC.ALOCN_SRC_CD = BS.ALOCN_SRC_CD
               AND DEST_BUP_ALSRC.ALOCN_LVL_NUM > @LVL_NUM
     LEFT JOIN [MISProcess].[udf_MR_BLOCK_STD_COST_PCT](@DATA_DT_ID) AS BLOCK_STD_COST_PCT
            ON BLOCK_STD_COST_PCT.FROM_ALOCN_SRC_CD = BALANCES.BUS_UNIT_ID
     LEFT JOIN [MISProcess].[udf_MR_BLOCK_NOT](@DATA_DT_ID) AS BLOCK_NOT
            ON BLOCK_NOT.ALOCN_SRC_CD = BALANCES.BUS_UNIT_ID
     LEFT JOIN [MISProcess].[udf_MR_BLOCK](@DATA_DT_ID) AS BLOCK
            ON BLOCK_NOT.ALOCN_SRC_CD IS NULL
               AND BLOCK.FROM_ALOCN_SRC_CD = BALANCES.BUS_UNIT_ID
               AND (
                    BLOCK.FROM_PROD_LINE_CD IS NULL
                    OR BLOCK.FROM_PROD_LINE_CD = BALANCES.BUS_UNIT_PROD_LINE_CD
                   )
     LEFT JOIN [MISProcess].[udf_MR_BLOCK_ALOCN_PAIRS](@DATA_DT_ID, @LVL_NUM)
            AS BLOCK_ALOCN_PAIRS
            ON BLOCK_NOT.ALOCN_SRC_CD IS NOT NULL
               AND BLOCK_ALOCN_PAIRS.FROM_ALOCN_SRC_CD = BALANCES.BUS_UNIT_ID
               AND BLOCK_ALOCN_PAIRS.TO_ALOCN_SRC_CD = BS.ALOCN_SRC_CD
     WHERE  BLOCK_ALOCN_PAIRS.TO_ALOCN_SRC_CD IS NULL
            AND BLOCK_STD_COST_PCT.FROM_ALOCN_SRC_CD IS NULL
            AND (
                 BLOCK.TO_ALOCN_SRC_CD IS NULL
                 OR BLOCK.TO_ALOCN_SRC_CD = BS.ALOCN_SRC_CD
                )
            AND (
                 BLOCK.TO_PROD_LINE_CD IS NULL
                 OR BLOCK.TO_PROD_LINE_CD = BS.PROD_LINE_CD
                )
            AND (
                 BLOCK.YEAR_NUM IS NULL
                 OR BLOCK.YEAR_NUM = BALANCES.YYMM_ID / 10000
                )
            AND (
                 BLOCK.MTH_NUM IS NULL
                 OR BLOCK.MTH_NUM = (BALANCES.YYMM_ID / 100) % 100
                )
            AND (
                 BLOCK.TO_DIV_NUM IS NULL
                 OR BLOCK.TO_DIV_NUM = DEST_BUP_ALSRC.DIV_NUM
                )
            AND (
                 BLOCK.TO_GRP_NUM IS NULL
                 OR BLOCK.TO_GRP_NUM = DEST_BUP_ALSRC.DIV_GRP
                )
            AND (
                 BLOCK.TO_REGN_GRP_NM IS NULL
                 OR BLOCK.TO_REGN_GRP_NM = DEST_BUP_ALSRC.REGN_GRP_NM
                )
            AND (
                 BLOCK.TO_REGN_NM IS NULL
                 OR BLOCK.TO_REGN_NM = DEST_BUP_ALSRC.REGN_NM
                )
            AND (
                 BLOCK.TO_ARENA_NM IS NULL
                 OR BLOCK.TO_ARENA_NM = DEST_BUP_ALSRC.ARENA_NM
                )
            AND (
                 BLOCK.TO_SUB_REGN_NM IS NULL
                 OR BLOCK.TO_SUB_REGN_NM = DEST_BUP_ALSRC.SUB_REGN_NM
                )
            AND (
                 BLOCK.TO_SUB_ARENA_NM IS NULL
                 OR BLOCK.TO_SUB_ARENA_NM = DEST_BUP_ALSRC.SUB_ARENA_NM
                )
     GROUP BY BALANCES.YYMM_ID
           ,BS.ALOCN_SRC_CD
           ,BS.PROD_LINE_CD
           ,BALANCES.BUS_UNIT_ID
           ,BALANCES.BUS_UNIT_PROD_LINE_CD
           ,BALANCES.ORIG_ALOCN_SRC_CD
           ,BALANCES.ALOCN_LINE_ITEM_NUM
    )

/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [MISProcess].[udf_MR_ALOCN_SUMRY_STAT_UNI]    Script Date: 05/14/2009 22:16:28 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE FUNCTION [MISProcess].[udf_MR_ALOCN_SUMRY_STAT_UNI] (
     @DATA_DT_ID int
    ,@LVL_NUM int
    )
RETURNS TABLE
--    WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS 
RETURN
    (
     SELECT YYMM_ID
           ,ALOCN_SRC_CD
           ,ALOCN_SRC_PROD_LINE_CD
           ,ORIG_ALOCN_SRC_CD
           ,ALOCN_LINE_ITEM_NUM
           ,SUM(ACCT_STATS_CNT) AS ACCT_STATS_CNT
     FROM   [MISProcess].[udf_MR_ALOCNS_STAT_UNI](@DATA_DT_ID, @LVL_NUM) AS ALOCNS
     GROUP BY YYMM_ID
           ,ALOCN_SRC_CD
           ,ALOCN_SRC_PROD_LINE_CD
           ,ORIG_ALOCN_SRC_CD
           ,ALOCN_LINE_ITEM_NUM
    )
```

This is my testing batch which will eventually run the entire process in a single SP.  You can see from commented out sections that I've been playing with temporary tables and table variables as well:

```
USE PCAPFIN

DECLARE @DATA_DT_ID_use AS int
DECLARE @MinLevel AS int
DECLARE @MaxLevel AS int
DECLARE @TestEveryLevel AS bit
DECLARE @TestFinal AS bit

SET @DATA_DT_ID_use = 20090331
SET @MinLevel = 6
SET @MaxLevel = 6
SET @TestEveryLevel = 0
SET @TestFinal = 1

--DECLARE @BALANCES TABLE (
--     METHOD_TXT varchar(12) NOT NULL
--    ,YYMM_ID int NOT NULL
--    ,BUS_UNIT_ID varchar(6) NOT NULL
--    ,BUS_UNIT_PROD_LINE_CD varchar(4) NOT NULL
--    ,ALOCN_SRC_PROD_LINE_CD varchar(4) NOT NULL
--    ,ORIG_ALOCN_SRC_CD varchar(6) NOT NULL
--    ,ALOCN_LINE_ITEM_NUM int NOT NULL
--    ,ANULZD_ACTL_BAL money
--    )
--
--DECLARE @ALOCNS TABLE (
--     METHOD_TXT varchar(12) NOT NULL
--    ,YYMM_ID int NOT NULL
--    ,BUS_UNIT_ID varchar(6) NOT NULL
--    ,BUS_UNIT_PROD_LINE_CD varchar(4) NOT NULL
--    ,ALOCN_SRC_CD varchar(6) NOT NULL
--    ,ALOCN_SRC_PROD_LINE_CD varchar(4) NOT NULL
--    ,ORIG_ALOCN_SRC_CD varchar(6) NOT NULL
--    ,ALOCN_LINE_ITEM_NUM int NOT NULL
--    ,ACCT_STATS_CNT money
--    )
--
--DECLARE @ALOCN_SUMRY TABLE (
--     METHOD_TXT varchar(12) NOT NULL
--    ,YYMM_ID int NOT NULL
--    ,ALOCN_SRC_CD varchar(6) NOT NULL
--    ,ALOCN_SRC_PROD_LINE_CD varchar(4) NOT NULL
--    ,ORIG_ALOCN_SRC_CD varchar(6) NOT NULL
--    ,ALOCN_LINE_ITEM_NUM int NOT NULL
--    ,ACCT_STATS_CNT money
--    )

--IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#BALANCES') IS NOT NULL 
--    DROP TABLE #BALANCES
--
--CREATE TABLE #BALANCES (
--     METHOD_TXT varchar(12) NOT NULL
--    ,YYMM_ID int NOT NULL
--    ,BUS_UNIT_ID varchar(6) NOT NULL
--    ,BUS_UNIT_PROD_LINE_CD varchar(4) NOT NULL
--    ,ALOCN_SRC_PROD_LINE_CD varchar(4) NOT NULL
--    ,ORIG_ALOCN_SRC_CD varchar(6) NOT NULL
--    ,ALOCN_LINE_ITEM_NUM int NOT NULL
--    ,ANULZD_ACTL_BAL money
--    ,CONSTRAINT [PK_BALANCES] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([METHOD_TXT] ASC, [YYMM_ID] ASC, [BUS_UNIT_ID] ASC, [BUS_UNIT_PROD_LINE_CD] ASC, [ALOCN_SRC_PROD_LINE_CD] ASC, [ORIG_ALOCN_SRC_CD] ASC, [ALOCN_LINE_ITEM_NUM] ASC)
--        WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
--              IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
--              ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
--    )
--
--IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ALOCN_SUMRY') IS NOT NULL 
--    DROP TABLE #ALOCNS
--
--CREATE TABLE #ALOCNS (
--     METHOD_TXT varchar(12) NOT NULL
--    ,YYMM_ID int NOT NULL
--    ,BUS_UNIT_ID varchar(6) NOT NULL
--    ,BUS_UNIT_PROD_LINE_CD varchar(4) NOT NULL
--    ,ALOCN_SRC_CD varchar(6) NOT NULL
--    ,ALOCN_SRC_PROD_LINE_CD varchar(4) NOT NULL
--    ,ORIG_ALOCN_SRC_CD varchar(6) NOT NULL
--    ,ALOCN_LINE_ITEM_NUM int NOT NULL
--    ,ACCT_STATS_CNT money
--    ,CONSTRAINT [PK_ALOCNS] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([METHOD_TXT] ASC, YYMM_ID ASC, BUS_UNIT_ID ASC, BUS_UNIT_PROD_LINE_CD ASC, ALOCN_SRC_CD ASC, ALOCN_SRC_PROD_LINE_CD ASC, ORIG_ALOCN_SRC_CD ASC, ALOCN_LINE_ITEM_NUM ASC)
--        WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
--              IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
--              ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
--    )
--
--IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ALOCN_SUMRY') IS NOT NULL 
--    DROP TABLE #ALOCN_SUMRY
--CREATE TABLE #ALOCN_SUMRY (
--     METHOD_TXT varchar(12) NOT NULL
--    ,YYMM_ID int NOT NULL
--    ,ALOCN_SRC_CD varchar(6) NOT NULL
--    ,ALOCN_SRC_PROD_LINE_CD varchar(4) NOT NULL
--    ,ORIG_ALOCN_SRC_CD varchar(6) NOT NULL
--    ,ALOCN_LINE_ITEM_NUM int NOT NULL
--    ,ACCT_STATS_CNT money
--    ,CONSTRAINT [PK_ALOCN_SUMRY] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([METHOD_TXT] ASC, YYMM_ID ASC, ALOCN_SRC_CD ASC, ALOCN_SRC_PROD_LINE_CD ASC, ORIG_ALOCN_SRC_CD ASC, ALOCN_LINE_ITEM_NUM ASC)
--        WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
--              IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
--              ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
--    )

SET @MinLevel = (
                 SELECT MIN(BUPALSRC.ALOCN_LVL_NUM)
                 FROM   MISProcess.LKP_BUPALSRC AS BUPALSRC
                 WHERE  BUPALSRC.DATA_DT_ID = @DATA_DT_ID_use
                        AND BUPALSRC.ALOCN_LVL_NUM >= @MinLevel
                )

DECLARE @Restart AS bit
IF @MinLevel > (
                SELECT  MIN(BUPALSRC.ALOCN_LVL_NUM)
                FROM    MISProcess.LKP_BUPALSRC AS BUPALSRC
                WHERE   BUPALSRC.DATA_DT_ID = @DATA_DT_ID_use
               ) 
    SET @Restart = 0
ELSE 
    SET @Restart = 1

DECLARE @subset_criteria AS varchar(max)

SET NOCOUNT ON

IF @Restart = 1 
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('Restarting process', 10, 1) WITH NOWAIT
--        TRUNCATE TABLE MISWork.AB
        DELETE FROM MISWork.AB

        INSERT  INTO MISWork.AB (
                 YYMM_ID
                ,BUS_UNIT_ID
                ,BUS_UNIT_PROD_LINE_CD
                ,ALOCN_SRC_CD
                ,ALOCN_SRC_PROD_LINE_CD
                ,ORIG_ALOCN_SRC_CD
                ,LINE_ITEM_NUM
                ,BAL_ORIGTN_IND
                ,ANULZD_ACTL_BAL
                ,ACCT_STATS_CNT
                ,LVL_NUM
                ,METHOD_TXT
                )
                SELECT  YYMM_ID
                       ,ALOCN_SRC_CD AS BUS_UNIT_ID
                       ,PROD_LINE_CD AS BUS_UNIT_PROD_LINE_CD
                       ,ALOCN_SRC_CD
                       ,PROD_LINE_CD AS ALOCN_SRC_PROD_LINE_CD
                       ,ALOCN_SRC_CD AS ORIG_ALOCN_SRC_CD
                       ,LINE_ITEM_NUM
                       ,'D' AS BAL_ORIGTN_IND
                       ,FIN_ALOCN_AMT AS ANULZD_ACTL_BAL
                       ,0.0 AS ACCT_STATS_CNT
                       ,0 AS LVL_NUM
                       ,'D-INIT' AS METHOD_TXT
    --        FROM    MISProcess.FIN_FTP
                FROM    PUASFIN.FocusResults.BUPALLGE
    END
ELSE 
    BEGIN
        DELETE  FROM MISWork.AB
        WHERE   LVL_NUM >= @MinLevel
    END

DECLARE @LVL_NUM AS int
SET @LVL_NUM = @MinLevel
WHILE @LVL_NUM <= @MaxLevel
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @LevelStart AS varchar(50)
        SET @LevelStart = 'Level:' + CONVERT(varchar, @LVL_NUM)
        RAISERROR (@LevelStart, 10, 1) WITH NOWAIT

        RAISERROR ('STD_COST_PCT allocations - No D - B records', 10, 1) WITH NOWAIT
        -- STD_COST_PCT allocations - No D - B records
        INSERT  INTO MISWork.AB (
                 YYMM_ID
                ,BUS_UNIT_ID
                ,BUS_UNIT_PROD_LINE_CD
                ,ALOCN_SRC_CD
                ,ALOCN_SRC_PROD_LINE_CD
                ,ORIG_ALOCN_SRC_CD
                ,LINE_ITEM_NUM
                ,BAL_ORIGTN_IND
                ,ANULZD_ACTL_BAL
                ,ACCT_STATS_CNT
                ,LVL_NUM
                ,METHOD_TXT
                )
                SELECT  ALOCNS.YYMM_ID
                       ,ALOCNS.BUS_UNIT_ID
                       ,ALOCNS.BUS_UNIT_PROD_LINE_CD
                       ,ALOCNS.BUS_UNIT_ID AS ALOCN_SRC_CD
                       ,ALOCNS.BUS_UNIT_PROD_LINE_CD AS ALOCN_SRC_PROD_LINE_CD
                       ,ALOCNS.BUS_UNIT_ID AS ORIG_ALOCN_SRC_CD
                       ,ALOCNS.LINE_ITEM_NUM
                       ,'B' AS BAL_ORIGTN_IND
                       ,-1.0 * ROUND(ALOCNS.ANULZD_ACTL_BAL, 2) AS ANULZD_ACTL_BAL
                       ,ROUND(ALOCNS.ACCT_STATS_CNT, 2) AS ACCT_STATS_CNT
                       ,@LVL_NUM AS LVL_NUM
                       ,'NO-D-B' AS METHOD_TXT
                FROM    [MISProcess].[udf_MR_ALOCNS_STD_COST_PCT_NO_D](@DATA_DT_ID_use, @LVL_NUM)
                        AS ALOCNS

        RAISERROR ('STD_COST_PCT allocations - No D - A records', 10, 1) WITH NOWAIT
        -- STD_COST_PCT allocations - No D - A records
        INSERT  INTO MISWork.AB (
                 YYMM_ID
                ,BUS_UNIT_ID
                ,BUS_UNIT_PROD_LINE_CD
                ,ALOCN_SRC_CD
                ,ALOCN_SRC_PROD_LINE_CD
                ,ORIG_ALOCN_SRC_CD
                ,LINE_ITEM_NUM
                ,BAL_ORIGTN_IND
                ,ANULZD_ACTL_BAL
                ,ACCT_STATS_CNT
                ,LVL_NUM
                ,METHOD_TXT
                )
                SELECT  ALOCNS.YYMM_ID
                       ,BLOCK.TO_ALOCN_SRC_CD AS BUS_UNIT_ID
                       ,ALOCNS.ALOCN_SRC_PROD_LINE_CD AS BUS_UNIT_PROD_LINE_CD
                       ,ALOCNS.ALOCN_SRC_CD
                       ,ALOCNS.BUS_UNIT_PROD_LINE_CD AS ALOCN_SRC_PROD_LINE_CD
                       ,ALOCNS.ORIG_ALOCN_SRC_CD
                       ,ALOCNS.LINE_ITEM_NUM
                       ,'A' AS BAL_ORIGTN_IND
                       ,ROUND(ALOCNS.ANULZD_ACTL_BAL, 2) AS ANULZD_ACTL_BAL
                       ,ROUND(ALOCNS.ACCT_STATS_CNT, 2) AS ACCT_STATS_CNT
                       ,@LVL_NUM AS LVL_NUM
                       ,'NO-D-A' AS METHOD_TXT
                FROM    [MISProcess].[udf_MR_ALOCNS_STD_COST_PCT_NO_D](@DATA_DT_ID_use, @LVL_NUM)
                        AS ALOCNS
                INNER JOIN MISProcess.LKP_BLOCK AS BLOCK
                        -- TODO: Can this be moved into the udf above?
                            ON BLOCK.DATA_DT_ID = @DATA_DT_ID_use
                               AND BLOCK.FROM_ALOCN_SRC_CD = ALOCNS.BUS_UNIT_ID

        RAISERROR ('STD_COST_PCT allocations - B records', 10, 1) WITH NOWAIT

        -- STD_COST_PCT allocations - B records
        INSERT  INTO MISWork.AB (
                 YYMM_ID
                ,BUS_UNIT_ID
                ,BUS_UNIT_PROD_LINE_CD
                ,ALOCN_SRC_CD
                ,ALOCN_SRC_PROD_LINE_CD
                ,ORIG_ALOCN_SRC_CD
                ,LINE_ITEM_NUM
                ,BAL_ORIGTN_IND
                ,ANULZD_ACTL_BAL
                ,ACCT_STATS_CNT
                ,LVL_NUM
                ,METHOD_TXT
                )
                SELECT  ALOCNS.YYMM_ID
                       ,ALOCNS.BUS_UNIT_ID
                       ,ALOCNS.BUS_UNIT_PROD_LINE_CD
                       ,ALOCNS.ALOCN_SRC_CD
                       ,ALOCNS.BUS_UNIT_PROD_LINE_CD AS ALOCN_SRC_PROD_LINE_CD
                       ,ALOCNS.ORIG_ALOCN_SRC_CD
                       ,ALOCNS.LINE_ITEM_NUM
                       ,'B' AS BAL_ORIGTN_IND
                       ,-1.0 * ROUND(ALOCNS.ANULZD_ACTL_BAL * RATIOS.RATIO, 2) AS ANULZD_ACTL_BAL
                       ,ROUND(ALOCNS.ACCT_STATS_CNT, 2) AS ACCT_STATS_CNT
                       ,@LVL_NUM AS LVL_NUM
                       ,'STD-B' AS METHOD_TXT
                FROM    [MISProcess].[udf_MR_ALOCNS_STD_COST_PCT](@DATA_DT_ID_use, @LVL_NUM)
                        AS ALOCNS
                INNER JOIN [MISProcess].[udf_MR_RATIOS_STD_COST_PCT](@DATA_DT_ID_use, @LVL_NUM)
                        AS RATIOS
                        ON RATIOS.YYMM_ID = ALOCNS.YYMM_ID
                           AND RATIOS.BUS_UNIT_ID = ALOCNS.BUS_UNIT_ID
                           AND RATIOS.LINE_ITEM_NUM = ALOCNS.LINE_ITEM_NUM

        RAISERROR ('STD_COST_PCT allocations - A records', 10, 1) WITH NOWAIT

        -- STD_COST_PCT allocations - A records
        ;
        WITH    CORRECTED_ALOCNS
                  AS (
                      SELECT    ALOCNS.YYMM_ID
                               ,ALOCNS.BUS_UNIT_ID
                               ,ALOCNS.BUS_UNIT_PROD_LINE_CD
                               ,ALOCNS.ALOCN_SRC_CD
                               ,ALOCNS.ALOCN_SRC_PROD_LINE_CD
                               ,ALOCNS.ORIG_ALOCN_SRC_CD
                               ,ALOCNS.LINE_ITEM_NUM
                               ,ALOCNS.ANULZD_ACTL_BAL * RATIOS.RATIO AS ANULZD_ACTL_BAL
                               ,CASE WHEN RATIOS.RATIO <> 1.0
                                     THEN RATIOS.RATIO
                                     ELSE ALOCNS.ACCT_STATS_CNT
                                END AS ACCT_STATS_CNT
                      FROM      [MISProcess].[udf_MR_CORR_ALOCNS_STD_COST_PCT](@DATA_DT_ID_use, @LVL_NUM)
                                AS ALOCNS
                      INNER JOIN [MISProcess].[udf_MR_RATIOS_STD_COST_PCT](@DATA_DT_ID_use, @LVL_NUM)
                                AS RATIOS
                                ON RATIOS.YYMM_ID = ALOCNS.YYMM_ID
                                   AND RATIOS.BUS_UNIT_ID = ALOCNS.ALOCN_SRC_CD
                                   AND RATIOS.LINE_ITEM_NUM = ALOCNS.LINE_ITEM_NUM
                     ),
                ROUNDED_ALOCNS
                  AS (
                      SELECT    YYMM_ID
                               ,BUS_UNIT_ID
                               ,BUS_UNIT_PROD_LINE_CD
                               ,ALOCN_SRC_CD
                               ,ALOCN_SRC_PROD_LINE_CD
                               ,ORIG_ALOCN_SRC_CD
                               ,LINE_ITEM_NUM
                               ,CASE WHEN ABS(ANULZD_ACTL_BAL) < 0.05 THEN 0.0
                                     WHEN ABS(ANULZD_ACTL_BAL) > 0.05
                                          AND ABS(ANULZD_ACTL_BAL) < 0.10
                                     THEN 0.10 * SIGN(ANULZD_ACTL_BAL)
                                     ELSE ANULZD_ACTL_BAL
                                END AS ANULZD_ACTL_BAL
                               ,ACCT_STATS_CNT
                      FROM      CORRECTED_ALOCNS
                     )
            INSERT  INTO MISWork.AB (
                     YYMM_ID
                    ,BUS_UNIT_ID
                    ,BUS_UNIT_PROD_LINE_CD
                    ,ALOCN_SRC_CD
                    ,ALOCN_SRC_PROD_LINE_CD
                    ,ORIG_ALOCN_SRC_CD
                    ,LINE_ITEM_NUM
                    ,BAL_ORIGTN_IND
                    ,ANULZD_ACTL_BAL
                    ,ACCT_STATS_CNT
                    ,LVL_NUM
                    ,METHOD_TXT
                    )
                    SELECT  YYMM_ID
                           ,BUS_UNIT_ID
                           ,BUS_UNIT_PROD_LINE_CD
                           ,ALOCN_SRC_CD
                           ,ALOCN_SRC_PROD_LINE_CD
                           ,ORIG_ALOCN_SRC_CD
                           ,LINE_ITEM_NUM
                           ,'A' AS BAL_ORIGTN_IND
                           ,ROUND(ANULZD_ACTL_BAL, 2) AS ANULZD_ACTL_BAL
                           ,ROUND(ACCT_STATS_CNT, 2) AS ACCT_STATS_CNT
                           ,@LVL_NUM AS LVL_NUM
                           ,'STD-A' AS METHOD_TXT
                    FROM    ROUNDED_ALOCNS
                    WHERE   ANULZD_ACTL_BAL <> 0.0
                            OR ACCT_STATS_CNT <> 0.0

        RAISERROR ('COLLAPSE, BLOCK 100 ALOCN_PCT - B records', 10, 1) WITH NOWAIT

        -- COLLAPSE, BLOCK 100% ALOCN_PCT - B records
        INSERT  INTO MISWork.AB (
                 YYMM_ID
                ,BUS_UNIT_ID
                ,BUS_UNIT_PROD_LINE_CD
                ,ALOCN_SRC_CD
                ,ALOCN_SRC_PROD_LINE_CD
                ,ORIG_ALOCN_SRC_CD
                ,LINE_ITEM_NUM
                ,BAL_ORIGTN_IND
                ,ANULZD_ACTL_BAL
                ,ACCT_STATS_CNT
                ,LVL_NUM
                ,METHOD_TXT
                )
                SELECT  BALANCES.YYMM_ID
                       ,BALANCES.BUS_UNIT_ID
                       ,BALANCES.BUS_UNIT_PROD_LINE_CD
                       ,BALANCES.BUS_UNIT_ID AS ALOCN_SRC_CD
                       ,BALANCES.BUS_UNIT_PROD_LINE_CD AS ALOCN_SRC_PROD_LINE_CD
                       ,BALANCES.ORIG_ALOCN_SRC_CD
                       ,BALANCES.ALOCN_LINE_ITEM_NUM AS LINE_ITEM_NUM
                       ,'B' AS BAL_ORIGTN_IND
                       ,-1.0 * BALANCES.ANULZD_ACTL_BAL
                       ,ALOCN_SUMRY.ACCT_STATS_CNT
                       ,@LVL_NUM AS LVL_NUM
                       ,'BLOCK-100' AS METHOD_TXT
                FROM    [MISProcess].[udf_MR_BALANCES_BLOCK_100_PCT](@DATA_DT_ID_use, @LVL_NUM)
                        AS BALANCES
                INNER JOIN [MISProcess].[udf_MR_ALOCN_SUMRY_BLOCK_100_PCT](@DATA_DT_ID_use, @LVL_NUM)
                        AS ALOCN_SUMRY
                        ON ALOCN_SUMRY.YYMM_ID = BALANCES.YYMM_ID
                           AND ALOCN_SUMRY.BUS_UNIT_ID = BALANCES.BUS_UNIT_ID
                           AND ALOCN_SUMRY.BUS_UNIT_PROD_LINE_CD = BALANCES.BUS_UNIT_PROD_LINE_CD
                           AND ALOCN_SUMRY.ALOCN_SRC_CD = BALANCES.ALOCN_SRC_CD
                           AND ALOCN_SUMRY.ALOCN_SRC_PROD_LINE_CD = BALANCES.ALOCN_SRC_PROD_LINE_CD
                           AND ALOCN_SUMRY.ORIG_ALOCN_SRC_CD = BALANCES.ORIG_ALOCN_SRC_CD

        RAISERROR ('COLLAPSE, BLOCK 100 ALOCN_PCT - A records', 10, 1) WITH NOWAIT

        -- COLLAPSE, BLOCK 100% ALOCN_PCT - A records
        INSERT  INTO MISWork.AB (
                 YYMM_ID
                ,BUS_UNIT_ID
                ,BUS_UNIT_PROD_LINE_CD
                ,ALOCN_SRC_CD
                ,ALOCN_SRC_PROD_LINE_CD
```

Comment: It looks like I ran into a limit of the question size on SO, so the actual calls to the particular matched set of UDFs I gave are missing, but the calls are similar to the ones which do show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the recompile should extend to the TV UDFS.

However, I'd use parameter masking not RECOMPILE.

1. With queries like this, complation will be expensive
2. When the UDFs are unnested, the parameter masking will apply too. TV UDFs do not have a plan as such: they are part of the calling query because they are unnested.

Can you break out some UDF calls into temporary tables and then join on the temp tables? 
I bet that when the UDFs are unnested, the query is simply too complex to run efficiently. The optimiser could take a week to find the ideal plan with something so complex. With temp tables (not table variables), I guess you'll get respectable improvements.

I've used this technique myself in some larger queries (generating pricing trees for financial instruments)

The fact you 150,000 rows is overshadowed by the sheer complexity I reckon.

**Edit**:

TVFs do not need parameter masking because they are only macros. You could literally replace it with a CTE or derived table.

See my answer here: [Does query plan optimizer works well with joined/filtered table-valued functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311026/does-query-plan-optimizer-works-well-with-joined-filtered-table-valued-functions/311163#311163)
And [Tony Rogerson on Views](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/tonyrogerson/archive/2008/01/03/views-they-offer-no-optimisation-benefits-they-are-simply-inline-macros-use-sparingly.aspx)

Comment: I assume you mean parameter masking in the SP.  Because when I initially looked at it, I couldn't find a way to do parameter masking in an inline TVF.  Yes, I do that for every SP.  I wish we were using 2008 so we could use the OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN option.

Comment: You don't need to maska TVF because it is not a discrete objects. It's expanded into the containing query. Updated answer

Answer (score 0):

One of the things to watch out for with table-valued functions (especially the multi-statement table valued functions) is that the resultant table, just like a table variable, has no column statistics and no indexes.

I tend to use TVFs with caution.

Comment: Even at level 6, the tables returned by the function are tiny - I think 150,000 rows.

Comment: And these are all inline table valued functions.

Comment: Which I understand to be basically reated as parameterized views - i.e. the optimizer can collapse them and push them together as it would if they were written out inline.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the actual T-SQL rather that pseudo-SQL? 
What you describe sounds like tables scans on larger and larger results sets as @LVL_NUM increases and probably RECOMPILE won't help there. But, based on pseudo-SQL, is really hard to give anything more than a pseudo-guess...

Comment: Seems that the test case was trunctated in the post and from the code itself the udf_MR_ALSRC is missing. Can you also give the ballpark of the table sizes for the participant tables?

Comment: Also, I see you tried to add SCHEMABINDING, why did you remove it?

Comment: Have you compared the actual execution plan of the query as you increase @LVL_NUM? If your theory is correct then the plan would change replacing good access paths (seeks) with bad access paths (scan). If my theory is correct then the plan would stay the same but the weight of execution would increase exponentially from repeated executions at higher @LVL_NUM (you'll see elements with ever increasing 'number of executions' in the plan).

Comment: The execution plan doesn't seem to be changing if I run one level at a time.  Which led me to believe that the UDFs had some kind of cached plans.  Of course, when run in a loop, the same plan is used for each iteration, so that's probably the root cause.  I've noticed performance differences if I drop and recreate the UDFs, so there seems to be some caching there.

Comment: If you start directly with a high @LVL_NUM on a cold cache (DBCC FREESYTEMCACHE), do you get a better plan for it? 
Also, how much is execution time and how much is compilation, after you drop evict the plans from cache? SET STATISTICS TIME ON to get the compile time.

Comment: It's looking right now that the problem is rooted in a LEFT JOIN issue.  I've seen this before and had to change a LEFT JOIN WHERE right_key IS NULL to a WHERE NOT IN.  There's something quirky about this installation and the DBAs don't recognize it.  It's not consistent.

Comment: Inconsistent? Maybe the query optimizer is forced to choose suboptimal plans based on memory conditions. Ie. optimal plan requires hash join, but not enough memory is free, so you get nested loops join instead. Is it a 64 bit Os and 64 bit SQL? Also OR usually destroys a query SARG-ability.