# Really strange issue with Table Valued Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, user-defined-functions

I was getting some timeouts on my app when I was trying to call a specific stored procedure.  I isolated it down to a specific sproc and found that when I call a tablevalued function in that sproc with a parameter it takes forever to run.  But if I pass in a specific value (like 804) it will return quickly.

If I run it by itself with the parameter it runs fine, but when I add it back into the query with the parameter it runs forever....then swap out the param with a static value and it runs quickly?

Steps I have taken:

1. Dropped procedure and recreated.
2. Ran `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE` on all plans containing a similar query string.
3. Just a test db so I restored the db with last nights backup.

Another thing to note.  On another db on the same server...about the same amount of data it runs fine......very strange.

What am I overlooking? I really don't get it.

Comment: Related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/866722/t-sql-process-design-and-execution-plan-udf-parameter-sniffing

Comment: Make sure that the datatype of the function parameter and the SP parameter is identical. Also check the execution plans in both cases.

Comment: @amit_g: should make that an answer. It's a valid point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Parameter sniffing](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Parameter+sniffing)?

Sorry for the short answer, but worth reading some answers...

From me previously too

- [Stored Procedure failing on a specific user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272726/stored-procedure-failing-on-a-specific-user/275739#275739)

Comment: I linked to a related question you answered as well.

Comment: Thanks guys I will take a look...I appreciate the feedback.

Comment: Was statistics on one of the base tables in my view.  Thanks again for the info.